# Add to javascript array dynamically

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, arrays, dynamic

I have a javascript file that for a slider that gets imag url's from an array. How can I add image url's from code behind. I want to get the pictures url from database so I want to add images to the array from code behind. I use asp.net c#. the jquery file is like below:

```
$(function() {
    $('#ds_showcase').showcase({
        linksOn: 'images',
        css: {},
        animation: { autoCycle: true, type: 'horizontal-slider', interval: 4000, stopOnHover:true, speed: 1500, easefunction: 'easeOutBounce'},
        images: [
                  { url: 'Showcase_ds_images/lift-truck.jpg ', description: 'Title 2', link: '', target: '_self' },
                  { url: 'Showcase_ds_images/lifttruck2.jpg', description: 'Title 3', link: '', target: '_self' },
                  { url: 'Showcase_ds_images/lift-truck3.jpg', description: 'Title 4', link: '', target: '_self' },

        ],
        navigator: { position: 'bottom-right', orientation: 'horizontal', autoHide: false, showNumber: false,
            css: { padding: '10px'}, 
            item: { css: { height: '10px', width: '10px', backgroundColor: '#cccccc', borderColor: '#999999'},
                    cssHover: { backgroundColor: '#3399ff'},
                    cssSelected: { backgroundColor: '#3399ff', borderColor: '#3399ff'}
            }
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always do something like this:

```
var jsArr = [];
<%foreach(string img in images){%>
   jsArr.push('<%=img%>');
<%}%>
```

This code will generate the js with hardcoded strings from the server.
The js each client will see will be something like this:

```
 var jsArr = [];

    jsArr.push('http://server/img1.png');
    jsArr.push('http://server/img2.png');
    jsArr.push('http://server/img3.png');
```

In your case - Something like this:

```
$(function() {
    var jsArr = [];
    <%foreach(Image img in images){%>
       jsArr.push({url: '<%=img.url%>', description: '<%=img.desc%>', link: '', target:'_self'});
    <%}%>

    $('#ds_showcase').showcase({
        linksOn: 'images',
        css: {},
        animation: { autoCycle: true, type: 'horizontal-slider', interval: 4000, stopOnHover:true, speed: 1500, easefunction: 'easeOutBounce'},
        images: jsArr,
        navigator: { position: 'bottom-right', orientation: 'horizontal', autoHide: false, showNumber: false,
            css: { padding: '10px'}, 
            item: { css: { height: '10px', width: '10px', backgroundColor: '#cccccc', borderColor: '#999999'},
                    cssHover: { backgroundColor: '#3399ff'},
                    cssSelected: { backgroundColor: '#3399ff', borderColor: '#3399ff'}
            }
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: what is "images" in 'foreach(Image img in images)', can I get image url's from sql server database?

Comment: images = server side IEnumerable(if you work MVC them Model.Images)..This is just an example.